# Thomas Jefferson's Qur'an notes and declaration of Independence

Tags: islam, jefferson

[This book alludes](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0307268225) to  works of Thomas Jefferson studying [the Quran](http://quran.com/1) and taking notes on it before writing the "Declaration of Independence".

Also the book mentions that Jefferson had a personal copy of Quran , Where can we find the original notes of Jefferson on Quran?

Comment: I would *love* there to be some discovered link between Jefferson's study of the Qur'an and the US Declaration of Independence and subsequent Constitution. Wouldn't that put the cat amongst the pigeons... :-)

Comment: @LateralFractal Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Ali - I believe LF means that it would put the lie to the mantra of some groups that the USA is a "Christian nation", which is very far from the truth. Jefferson, Franklin, as well as several other of the important Founders were [Deists.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deism#Deism_in_the_United_States) _In the United States, Enlightenment philosophy (which itself was heavily inspired by deist ideals) played a major role in creating the principle of religious freedom, expressed in Thomas Jefferson's letters and included in the First Amendment to the United States Constitution._

Comment: Yes, especially given the sharp swing against Islamic and Arabic culture since the end of WWII. Oft-times the talking heads on TV tend to forget that this is a new prejudice. Many Americans and Europeans of the 18th and 19th century were [fascinated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Count_of_Monte_Cristo) with Arabia.

Comment: @Coelacanth Some of the Founding Fathers were deists, that is true. But not deists in the sense pf "I believe in one nebulous divine entity" but as a version of Christianity. They had all read their John Locke (religious freedom) but Locke wrote within a Christian context. Even the book that the OP refers to admits that Jefferson felt "personal disdain for the faith". Whatever goodwill he might have felt toward Islam surely evaporated by the time of the [First Barbary War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Barbary_War). File this Q under "Islam's desperate need for approval from the West".

Comment: If we take the book's blurb as an accurate summary of its content, however, the author is right about one thing: the Enlightenment era did see a fashion craze about things Islamic -- e.g., Mozart's _rondo alla turca_ and _Abduction from the Serail_ -- as well as a concerted attempt mostly by Protestant and Jewish writers to build up an imaginary "Golden Age of Islam" in Spain as a counterpoint to (perceived) Catholic intolerance and enforcement of conformity. It was mostly a myth, of course, but like many others Jefferson did get swept up in the fad... for a while.

Comment: Unrelated - why is the tag named "jefferson" instead of "thomas-jefferson"?

Comment: And related - perhaps the answer can be obtained from the [Jefferson foundation](http://www.monticello.org/site/about)

Comment: @EugeneSeidel Can you please be more specific about the "Golden Age of Islam" being a Protestant-Jewish construct? It's an interesting claim and I'd like to know more about it.

Comment: @Felix Will do, look for a posting from me in the near future.

Comment: @EugeneSeidel- _Deists_ - not touching it :-) ; _Golden Age_ : I'm with Felix:there was very important activity in science and math in the Arab world during that period (invention of Algebra etc.) and among the most important classical Jewish scholars lived at that time in Arab countries and produced some of the greatest works of classical theology, law and philosophy-most notable being [Maimonides](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maimonides) born in Córdoba, Almoravid Empire in 1135, died in Egypt on December 12, 1204. So please source **well** your claim that said _Golden Age_ is a fabrication.